# zsh set | grep VAR return Binary file (standard input) matches

Tags: shell, grep, zsh

I made a shell variable with `VARR="var"` and then `set | grep VARR` but I get back `Binary file (standard input) matches`. I'm using zsh but it should be the same as bash right and give me back `"var"` right??

Comment: Some other variable in the output of `set` contains non-ASCII characters, which causes `grep` to assume the entire output is a binary file.

Answer (score 1):

You locale is certainly not set according to the characters you inject in some of your variables.

Here is a workaround:

```
set | grep --binary-files=text VARR
```